# inspect getsource didn't response with annotation on a class

Tags: python, decorator, inspect

For exampel I have a class in Python:

```py
def dec(clz):
  return clz

@dec
class Test:
  pass
```

when I use `insepct.getsource(Test)` in python 3.8, the souce code has no `@dec`
But sourcecode will contain `@dec` when I use python 3.10

any information where this difference comes?
If I have to support 3.8 python, what function I need to use the get the annotation along with source code?

Thanks

Comment: That's not an annotation (see https://realpython.com/lessons/annotations/). It's a no-op decorator, the code of `Test` object is the value of `return clz`. It's nice that Python 3.10 has enhanced `getsource` to include the decorator application, but Python 3.8 behaviour is not really surprising.  Are you using this to analyse 3rd party code? If it's your own code, to know what decorators are applied to a class, you may be better to implement a registration pattern in the decorator instead of using inspect.

Comment: no idea if there's a better way but as a workaround you could try `inspect.getsourcelines` which returns a starting line number, and then (with `inspect.getsourcefile`) look for decorator applications at preceding lines in the src file until you find none